# cron not working with commands symlinked in custom PATH

Tags: cron, symlink, path

I have a script `job.sh` in `/home/user/scripts`, which is then symlinked to `/home/user/bin/job`. The custom binaries path has been included in `.bashrc`, so whenever I issue the command `job param1 etc` from the cli everything works as expected.

When said command has to be run through a cronjob, it doesn't. On the other hand, if the cronjob refers to the full path (`/home/user/bin/job` instead of simply `job`) everything runs fine.

Any pointer on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` intentionally runs with a limited environment (including a restricted path, it does not have the same path as your standard shell).

You either need to run a script (including the full path to the script) which then sets a path variable internally, or you need to set the path in the `crontab` line itself.

One example of that is,

`12 0 * * * (export PATH=$PATH:/somedirectory; job)`

Really though, it's safer to just include the full path to whatever you're running in the `crontab`, and set the path correctly in your scripts that `cron` executes.

Comment: got it, thanks for the clear explaination!